# Text analysis - classification, parsing

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, nlp

Excuse if this has been answered before.

I need to extract features and parse from a piece of text and run some analysis.
For e.g. "Plot the past 5-year sales of Apple" should give me the following

Information:

1. Company - Apple
2. Item - Sales
3. Period - past 5 years
4. Action - Plot

What deep learning techniques / algorithms should I be looking to use?

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Named-Entity Recognition (NER) is one of the techniques you could look at. Different techniques exist, you could first look at pre-trained models of Spacy in Python [here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features). Otherwise, you could train a model on your own training data if you have.

Also, more systematic approaches can be efficient. For exemple, looking at POS tags values, do regex identification...

More generally, this is the field of Information Extraction (IE) in text mining. Some good resources can be found [here](http://philipperemy.github.io/information-extract/) and [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html). Sorry, everything is in Python as I work mainly with it.

Good luck!